# Is User Logged In PHP Argument Syntax Error

Tags: php, html

The following line of my code has a syntax error - and I, for the life of me keep overlooking it.

```
<a href=\"http://drive.mywebsite.com/code-search?username=" echo $current_user->user_login "\" class=\"btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block\">OPEN APP</a>
```

Here's the full snippet

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo "
    ...Some HTML...

    <a href=\"http://drive.mywebsite.com/code-search?username=" echo $current_user->user_login "\" class=\"btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block\">OPEN APP</a>

    ...Some more HTML...

";} else { echo "

    ...Some more HTML for when the user is not logged in...

;} ?>
```

[Full Code Snippet](https://codeshare.io/xqoCw)

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: You can just place the HTML outside of the php tags (so `?>some html<?php`). That way you don't have to echo all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
<a href=\"http://drive.mywebsite.com/code-search?username=" echo $current_user->user_login "\" class=\"btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block\">OPEN APP</a>
```

by

```
<a href=\"http://drive.mywebsite.com/code-search?username=" . $current_user->user_login . "\" class=\"btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block\">OPEN APP</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

jiboulex' answer is correct, though you should not use echo for all of the HTML.

Try something like this:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
    ...Some HTML...

    <a href="http://drive.mywebsite.com/code-search?username=<?= $current_user->user_login ?>" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block">OPEN APP</a>

    ...Some more HTML...

<?php } else { ?>

    ...Some more HTML for when the user is not logged in...

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Ivar - helped greatly

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the line in questions with the following:

```
<a href='http://drive.mywebsite.com/code-search?username=".$current_user->user_login."' class='btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block\'>OPEN APP</a>
```

Worked out great!

I didn't need to ECHO when within an ECHO